# How do you mock a virtual binary file so that exec() / system() / passthru() function output can be tested?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I have an interesting problem and have searched the internet, but haven't yet found an answer.

I work for a company that doesn't allow it's workers to utilize OOP, it is kind of ridiculous, but the working experience is valuable.

Consider the following function:

```
function get_setting_values_from_file( $parameter )
{
    exec("/usr/var/binary --options $parameter", $output, $return);
    $settings = file( $output[0] );
    foreach( $settings as $setting ) {
        if( strstr( $setting, "color") ) {
            $setting = explode( ":", $setting );
            return $setting[1];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I need to unit test a similar function. I am currently using phpUnit for my tests and the vfsStream libraries to mock the file system, but how do you mock the call to `exec("/usr/var/binary --options $parameter", $output, $return)` when I'm developing with no access to the actual system? What is the recommend approach for dealing with test cases like this?

All feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply mock this function to return the text that you are trying to get into $settings.  You do not need to call the executable, simply create the file or return.

For instance, assuming the function get_setting_values_from_file() returns the settings as an array, you can simply mock the function in your test to return the settings as an array.  Create a test stub to mock the object that contains the get_setting_values_from_file() method, and have that mock simply return the same FALSE, 1 or 2 that the test assumed.

```
$stub = $this->getMock('GetSettingsClass');
    $stub->expects($this->any())
         ->method('get_settings_from_file')
         ->will($this->returnValue(0));
```

This is from the PHPUnit manual -> http://phpunit.de/manual/3.8/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs

Optionally, you could even bypass the call, and simply test the functions/code that works on the returns by creating the array and passing it to those functions.
Assumed Example in the main code:

```
...
$settings = get_setting_values_from_file( 'UserType' );
$UserType = get_user_type($settings);
return $UserType;

function get_user_type($settings)
{
    if($settings !== FALSE)         // Returned from your function if parameter is not found
    {
        switch($settings)
        {
            case 1:
                return 'User';      // Best to use Constants, but for example here only
                break;
            case 2:
                return 'Admin';
                break;
            ...
         }
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Now, in your test, you can simply

```
$this->assertFalse(get_user_type(FALSE, 'Ensure not found data is handled properly as FALSE is returned');
$this->assertEqual('User', get_user_type(1), 'Test UserType=1');
$this->assertEqual('Admin', get_user_type(1), 'Test UserType=2');
...
```

These work as the code does not call the function that had to mock the read from the OS, but does handle all the expected returns by calling the function processing the setting return value.  Here, you have simply assumed the return from the function 'get_setting_values_from_file()' without needing the file or any mocks.

This does NOT however test reading from the file, which I would do in another test by using the setUp and tearDown to actual create a file with the values you want (fopen/fwrite) and then call your function and ensure it returns what is expected.

I hope this helps to explain what I was thinking.

Comment: Steven, Thanks a lot for your feedback. I really appreciate it. What you said is the most sound way to deal with it. If there were a system for mocking that binary I would have to mock the entire OS. I just recently got into TDD and wanted to make sure that I had all of my bases covered.

Comment: Steven, the answer that you gave was correct, but I didn't quite know how to implement it. I did some research and you can implement it using namespaces. I posted a possible way to implement your solution using PHP namespaces at this site. (http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/457509/how-do-you-mock-a-binary-file-execution-for-unit-tests-with-phpunit)

Comment: Right now, the function you are calling does not return anything, but does set an internal variable $settings.  This is what you return.  I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Understood. Very good example. I read the PHPUnit manual and read about stubbing. I was under the impression that stubbing only worked on classes. My work place doesn't allow us to us classes, so I was stuck trying to test a function that ran a binary file. Mocking fopen and fwrite can be done with vfsStream, but mocking binary out put was what I was having problems with. Also, I have to apologize for not being clear, but I had to test the function get_setting_values_from_file as that was the function that I was making.

Comment: Yes, the mock is only for classes. The mock will then not work, but testing the returns and isolating the variables will allow you to test this.  For instance, you can expand the internals of the function to have the handling of the read on its own, so that it becomes another function, and one to set data accordingly, which will allow you to test that, and with the actual read in another function, you can simply call the functions to handle the data with test values. By using simple functions, you can test them and reuse the functions for other purposes. Share the read of parameters with data.

Comment: I reviewed the comment that you gave me on the $settings variable. I'm going to update my code here to reflect what I was thinking and my solution as well if that's okay.

Comment: Feel free to update the question.  I would be happy to provide additional help if I can.

Answer (score 7):

You could mock `exec()` by using a function mock library. I made one ([`php-mock`](https://github.com/php-mock/php-mock-phpunit)) for you which requires you to use namespaces

```
namespace foo;

use phpmock\phpunit\PHPMock;

class ExecTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    use PHPMock;

    public function testExec()
    {
        $mock = $this->getFunctionMock(__NAMESPACE__, "exec");
        $mock->expects($this->once())->willReturnCallback(
            function ($command, &$output, &$return_var) {
                $this->assertEquals("foo", $command);
                $output = "failure";
                $return_var = 1;
            }
        );

        exec("foo", $output, $return_var);
        $this->assertEquals("failure", $output);
        $this->assertEquals(1, $return_var);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna give this a shot.