# Suggestions for unit testing external cli tool (phpunit)

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am currently working on PHP project where I need to wrap external CLI tool that does something (not really important what that something is). I would like to unit test all that.

For example if I have a code that does this:

```php
function foo($cmdpath, $param1, $param2) {
  $output = [];
  $result = 0;
  exec(
   sprintf(
     '%s %s %s',
     escapeshellcmd($cmdpath),
     escapeshellarg($param1),
     escapeshellarg($param2)
   ),
   $output,
   $result
  );
  if ($result == 0) {
    echo 'We are ok!'
  }
}
```

This code assumes that command specified in `$cmdpath` exists and that it will return numeric result depending on execution result.

Should I just wrap exec into something else and make it behave differently when executed under PHPUNIT?

Can anybody suggest the reasonable strategy for doing this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29357900/1213708 shows how to mock exec - may be worth a try.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look.